# Properties of determinants via scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

With reference to item (iii), doesn't it have to be an "integer" rather than just a "scalar". Because I have seen instances where the property fails when the multiplication is done by fractions yet I have not seen any text book iterating that.

[image]

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    2 & -3 & 10 \\ 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & -3 
    \end{vmatrix}
    = -
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 & -2 \\ 2 & -3 & 10 \\ 0 & 0 & -3 
    \end{vmatrix}
    = -
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & -7 & 14 \\ 0 & 0 & -3 
    \end{vmatrix} \\
    =(-1)(-7)(-3)
    =-21
 $$

Instead of all this, had I multiplied the second row by $-1/7$ for an instance, the determinant would be different. Can someone explain me what I'm missing here ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us such an instance?

Comment: You  would have got $$7\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & -3 
    \end{vmatrix}$$ which would still equal $-21$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, could you explain why I get two answers as above and when I multiplied the second row by −1/7 ? Thank you.

Comment: My explanation, sorry to say, is that you sometimes make arithmetic mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't change!

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 \\ 4 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$

$\det(A) =8 - 16 = -8 $

> Multiply $R_2$ by $\frac{1}{4}$ a fraction

$B =  \begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

> $\det(B) = 2- 4 = -2 = \frac{1}{4}(-8) = \frac{1}{4}\det(A)$

If we multiply $R_2$ by zero,

$C =  \begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 \\ 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$

> $\det(C) = 0 = 0\det(A)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It works also if $k=0$. Then $B$ has a zero row and its determinant is $0$.